# Filtration strongly typed result

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a collection of parent entities and each parent entity **P** contains child entities **C**.

I want a filtered  **strongly type** collection/list of all parent entities whose any child's name is 'peter'

please note I need strongly types list in result.

```
List<P> parents = (List<P>)db.Ps.Select(a => a.Cs.Any(b => b.Name == "Peter")).ToList();
```

This code is returning `IEnumerable` which is not my need.
Note: this scenario and code is just an example for learning purposes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you want a filtered list of your parent entities you need to use [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx) instead of [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx). This should be what you want:

```
var res = db.Ps.Where(a => a.CS.Name == "Peter").ToList();
```

Or if you have `1-many`:

```
var res = db.Ps.Where(a => a.CS.Any(b => b.Name == "Peter")).ToList();
```

Which `res` is a List of your `Ps` class.

Comment: As OP is saying that `Cs` is actually Child entity (probably 1-many) therefore use of `Any` is valid here.

Comment: @sallushan As you said probably *1-many* or it could be 1-1. But yes if it is 1-many he could also use `Any`. BTW the main point of the answer is using `Where` to filter the sequence  instead of `Select`.

Comment: Yes, but you should change the answer, you are saying _Also You can't use Any here_

Comment: I was about to say the same while the edit appeared :-) . +1 here, this is the right answer (even more complete with the edit)

Comment: Great, its working, I tried where before in this problem but made a mistake in my selection criteria. thanks all.